# MySQL View performance issue with aggregate query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-view, mysql-5.6

I'm using mysql version 5.6.47. 
I have the following table for student marks:

```
CREATE TABLE `studentmarks` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StudentID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subjectName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MARKS` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `idx_studentmarks_StudentID` (`StudentID`)
);
```

and created a View on the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `vw_student_marks` AS
    SELECT 
        `s1`.`StudentID` AS `StudentID`,
        `s1`.`subjectName` AS `subjectName`,
        `s1`.`MARKS` AS `marks`,
        (SELECT 
                SUM(`s2`.`MARKS`)
            FROM
                `studentmarks` `s2`
            WHERE
                (`s2`.`StudentID` = `s1`.`StudentID`)) AS `totalMarks`
    FROM
        `studentmarks` `s1`;
```

When testing with around 20K rows, there is a noticeable difference in performance in running `SELECT query` vs `SELECT * FROM VIEW`. The select query shows an optimized execution plan with just 1 full table scan, while for view there are 2 full table scans.

Query Stats (Measured by MySQL Workbench):

SELECT QUERY

```
Timing: 0:00:0.07677120 (as measured by the server)

Rows Examined: 108285
```

SELECT FROM VIEW QUERY :

```
Timing: 0:00:1.6082441 (as measured by the server)

Rows Examined: 2985730
```

What is the reason behind this difference in performance?

Query Execution Plans: https://i.stack.imgur.com/noOxI.jpg

UPDATE: I tested with MySQL version 8.0.19, the same issue occurs

Comment: I really wouldn't bother with views in MySQL

Comment: `VIEWs` seem to be syntactic sugar; I have yet to hear of a `VIEW` that can beat the equivalent `SELECT` in performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL must be using TEMPTABLE algorithm for the view in this case (aggregate functions). This might be the reason for the difference.

You can refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html for more details.

> If the MERGE algorithm cannot be used, a temporary table must be used
>   instead. MERGE cannot be used if the view contains any of the
>   following constructs:
>
> Aggregate functions (SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), COUNT(), and so forth)
>
> DISTINCT
>
> GROUP BY
>
> HAVING
>
> LIMIT
>
> UNION or UNION ALL
>
> Subquery in the select list
>
> Assignment to user variables
>
> Refers only to literal values (in this case, there is no underlying
>   table)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I'd write this using an uncorrelated subquery (but I accept that it won't necessarily improve performance) - and dispense with the idea of using a view altogether...

```
SELECT s1.StudentID
     , s1.subjectName
     , s1.MARKS
     , s2.totalmarks
  FROM studentmarks s1
  JOIN
     ( SELECT studentid
            , SUM(s2.MARKS) totalmarks
         FROM studentmarks
        GROUP 
           BY studentid
     ) s2
    ON s2.studentid = s1.studentid;
```